# Mathematica 10 hangs when modifying plots/themes from Suggestions bar

Tags: labeling, predictive-interface, plot-themes

I am using *Mathematica 10* on a computer running *Windows 7 (64-bit)* with all the most recent updates from *Microsoft*.

My problem is as follows:

1. I create a plot using the `Plot[]` function.
2. When I click on the plot, the *Mathematica* suggestions bar appears under it, with items like `theme ..`, `labels ..`, `axes`, `image size`, `more`.
3. If I click on `theme`, `labels` or `axes`, *Mathematica* hangs.
4. If I click on `more`, a more detailed menu opens up underneath the plot, containing the same menu items (plus a few more). If I then click on `theme` or `label` or `axes` in this larger menu, *Mathematica* again hangs.

By "hang" I mean that *Mathematica* becomes unresponsive. CPU usage maxes out at near 100% (for one core of my CPU). I have waited as long as 15 minutes, but nothing changes, the program continues to be unresponsive.

At this point, I can only close and restart *Mathematica* through *Task Manager*.

Here is a screenshot showing the `theme` and `labels` buttons that make *Mathematica* hang up when clicked. I have circled them in red:

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing the *Windows*' "Application has become unresponsive" notice:

[image]

I have tried resetting the *Mathematica* interface by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys while starting *Mathematica*. This resets the interface all right, but the hanging problem persists.

**Can anyone reproduces it?**

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematica.SE! We appreciate the clear and thorough layout of your question, but I suspect that it might be better directed to Wolfram support.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I think this may be a localized issue.

Comment: I have encountered this issue in Mathematica 10.0.01 in Windows 7 Professional